# Change Default Microphone

Tags: audio, python-3, raspbian-buster, alsa, microphone

I am having trouble changing my default mic on raspbian buster lite (kernel 4.19.36 on the 3B+).
I know that the mic is fully functional because when I run: `arecord -D plughw:1,0 --duration=3 test.wav && aplay test.wav` it records and plays back my audio just fine. My issue is that this microphone is not the default.
My results from running `arecord -l` :

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Device [USB PnP Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have tried changing my .asoundrd and my /etc/asound.config file to:

```
pcm.!default {
type asym
playback.pcm "plughw:0"
capture.pcm  "plughw:1"
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

I have tried changing the lines from my /usr/share/alsa file from 

 `defaults.ctl.card 0
 defaults.pcm.card 0`

to

 `defaults.ctl.card 1
 defaults.pcm.card 1`

None of the above mentioned solutions have worked for me.

The reason why I am trying to change my default microphone is because I am developing a python project that uses the Snowboy Hotword Engine, and I have not been able to find a way to get it to reference a different mic. So, if anyone knows how to do that, I don't actually need to change the default mic.

Thank you